# Java mail PDF attachment not working

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am generating a PDF and trying to attach it to a mail as well as download it from browser using java. Download from browser works fine, but attaching to mail is where I am facing an issue. The file is attached. Attachment name and size of the file are intact. The problem is when I open the PDF from mail attachment, it shows nothing. correct number of pages with no content. When I attach the file downloaded from browser by hardcoding, it works fine. So I suppose the problem is not with the PDF generation. I tried opening both(one downloaded from browser and the other downloaded from mail) the files using comparing tool beyond compare. The one downloaded from mail shows conversion error. When I open with notepad++, both show different encoding. I not very familiar with these encoding thing. I suppose it is something to do with encoding.

I also observed that the content in mail download is same as the one at PDF generation. But the one at browser download is different.

An excerpt of what I get on browser download is as below(The content is too large to paste)

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
4 0 obj <</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 193/Length 11222/Height 58/Filter/DCTDecode>>stream
ÿØÿà
```

An excerpt of what I get on mail download is as below

```
%PDF-1.4
%????
4 0 obj <</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 193/Length 11222/Height 58/Filter/DCTDecode>>stream
????
```

I am using Spring MimeMessageHelper to send the message. I am using the below method to add attachment

```
MimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(fileName, new ByteArrayResource(attachmentContent.getBytes()), "application/pdf");
```

I've also tried another way of attaching but in vain

```
DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/pdf");
MimeBodyPart pdfBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
pdfBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");
pdfBodyPart.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
pdfBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
mimeMessageHelper.getMimeMultipart().addBodyPart(pdfBodyPart);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it but I noticed you're not setting the actual charset in `pdfBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf;charset");`, nor are you calling `attachmentContent.getBytes()` with a charset as parameter. How is it supposed to know which one you want to use?

Comment: Sorry some mistake in pasting. Corrected it.

Comment: Still not getting the content bytes with an encoding though.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. Did you mean the mail attachment has got a different encoding than UTF-8?

Comment: I'm saying you should probably call attachmentContent.getBytes("UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

What Content-Transfer-Encoding is being used for the attachment in the message you receive?  Normally JavaMail will choose an appropriate value, but if document contains an unusual mix of plain text and binary, as your document seems to, JavaMail may not choose the best encoding.  You can try adding pdfBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it was'nt working. It is an encoding issue but nothing to do with MimeMessageHelper. The problem was I generated the PDF to an OutputStream and converted it to String and then converted it into byte array. When I converted to it to String the encoding changed resulting in the issue. So i fixed it by getting byte array from outputStream :)